# PHP: Post name of <a> tag, then use on linked page

Tags: php, html

so basically lets say I have a page called **page-with-links.php**:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php" name="blue">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php" name="red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php" name="green">Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php" name="yellow">Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php" name="orange">Orange</a></li>
</ul>
```

and a page called **page-with-checkboxes.php**:

```
<h3>You selected:</h3>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="blue" />
    <label for="blue"> Blue</label><br>

    input type="checkbox" name="red" />
    <label for="red"> Red</label><br>

    input type="checkbox" name="green" />
    <label for="green"> Green</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="yellow" />
    <label for="yellow"> Yellow</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="orange" />
    <label for="orange"> Orange</label><br>
</form>
```

I would like to be able to use the **name** value of the `<a>` tag to check the related box on the next page.

For example, if the user clicks 'green' on **page-with-links.php**, I would like the checkbox with `name="green"` to be checked when **page-with-checkboxes.php** loads.

I hope I've been clear enough. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write line of code on your page **page-with-links.php**

`<ul>
    <li> <a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?value=blue" name="blue">Blue</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?value=red" name="red">Red</a></li>
    <li> <a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?value=green" name="green">Green</a></li>
    <li> <a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?value=yellow" name="yellow">Yellow</a></li>
    <li> <a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?value=orange" name="orange">Orange</a></li>
   </ul>`

and write  follow line of code on page called **page-with-checkboxes.php:**

`<input type="checkbox" name="blue" <?php echo $_GET['value']=='blue'?'checked':''; />
    <label for="blue"> Blue</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="red" <?php echo $_GET['value']=='red'?'checked':''; />
    <label for="red"> Red</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="green" <?php echo $_GET['value']=='green'?'checked':''; />
    <label for="green"> Green</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="yellow" <?php echo $_GET['value']=='yellow'?'checked':''; />
    <label for="yellow"> Yellow</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="orange" <?php echo $_GET['value']=='orange'?'checked':''; />
    <label for="orange"> Orange</label>`

Answer (score 1):

The `a` tag attributes does not affect on the request.

You must follow this :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?name=blue" name="blue">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?name=red" name="red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?name=green" name="green">Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?name=yellow" name="yellow">Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?name=orange" name="orange">Orange</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in your `page-with-checkboxes.php` get this values :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['name']) {
        $color = $_GET['name'];
    } else {
        $color = null;
    }
?>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="blue" <?php print $color=="blue" ? "checked" : "" ?> />
    <label for="blue"> Blue</label><br>

    input type="checkbox" name="red" <?php print $color=="red" ? "checked" : "" ?> />
    <label for="red"> Red</label><br>

    input type="checkbox" name="green" <?php print $color=="green" ? "checked" : "" ?> />
    <label for="green"> Green</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="yellow" <?php print $color=="yellow" ? "checked" : "" ?> />
    <label for="yellow"> Yellow</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="orange" <?php print $color=="orange" ? "checked" : "" ?> />
    <label for="orange"> Orange</label><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't get this to work for some reason... method posted by @SiwachGaurav worked great but I prefer your method as opposed using several `$_GET` requests. Any idea what I could have missed? Note that I added the missing chevrons on a couple of the `input` fields and still couldn't get it to work so that's not the problem. Thanks

Comment: oh I missed print function excuse me !!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

In  page-with-links.php:

```
  <li><a href="page-with-checkboxes.php?type=blue" name="blue">Blue</a></li>
```

In page-with-checkboxes.php:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="blue" <?php echo $_GET['type']=='blue'?'checked':''; />
 <label for="blue"> Blue</label><br>
```